# Adding a tag to ListView Item XAML [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm trying to add a tag to my ListView Item (like adding a tag to a button).

My XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="gamesList" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="gamesList_ItemClick">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid Height="200" Width="896">
                            <Rectangle Fill="#FFCCCCCC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="10,71,0,0" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="voteCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Votes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF107C10" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="voteCountText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,104,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="votes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF292C33"/>
                            <Button x:Name="voteButton" Tag="{Binding Slug, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{Binding BtnVoted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Background="#FF888888" Foreground="#FF292C33" Click="voteButton_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding BtnEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="voteTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" Foreground="#FF292C33"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="voteError" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="You already voted for this game" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding Voted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Margin="10,180,0,0" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="801"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

C# (Partially):

```
        public async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var response = await start();

            dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

            foreach (var item in dynJson)
            {
                Object votedGame = localSettings.Values[item.slug.ToString()];
                string voted = "Collapsed";
                string btnVoted = "VOTE";
                bool btnEnabled = true;

                if(votedGame != null)
                {
                    voted = "Visible";
                    btnVoted = "VOTED!";
                    btnEnabled = false;
                }

                listofGames.Add(new Games { Title = item.name, Votes = item.votes, Slug = item.slug, Voted = voted, BtnVoted = btnVoted, BtnEnabled = btnEnabled });
            }

            gamesList.ItemsSource = listofGames;
        }

        public class Games
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Slug { get; set; }
            public string Voted { get; set; }
            public string BtnVoted { get; set; }
            public bool BtnEnabled { get; set; }
            public int Votes { get; set; }
        }
```

The tag should contain data about (in this case) a game title.

So, when the user clicks the item a click function should handle the event and I need to be able to get the data from the tag.

Comment: How do you "add a tag to a button"? Are you talking about the `Tag` property? Don't do that, use MVVM. Also, a little off topic -- can you explain your `ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I was talking about the `Tag` property. I would like the same result for `ListViewItem` as for the `Button`. And I was following a tutorial, so I don't really know why `ItemContainerStyle` is there yet. I'm quite new to XAML

Comment: How are you populating the ListView? If the tutorial didn't tell you to bind an ObservableCollection to ListView.ItemsSource, it's a bad tutorial and you should find another.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Receiving the data through JSON and using a `foreach()` loop to loop through all the items from JSON, which then will be added to a `List<>`. The `List<>` is used as follows: `gamesList.ItemSource = listofGames;`

Comment: Oh, boy. No viewmodel? Anyway: What class are you populating the `List<T>` with?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Updated the post with some of the C#

Comment: Thanks. OK, so when the selection changes, the ListView's SelectedItem property will be the `Games` instance the user clicked on. Now we've got another problem, though: My ListView doesn't have an `ItemClick` event. Is this UWP or something?

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's correct. Probably should've mentioned that. Sorry

Comment: It's a bit of a mess in here.  `Tag={Binding whatevs, Mode=TwoWay` suggests you're lacking a lot of knowledge here.  Might want to invest in a couple books on the subject and do some reading.

Comment: @Will Right, I was having issues with `Binding` not updating. So I did some research and found this.

Comment: Do a deep dive into MVVM.  Once you get past the initial shock, things like this become trivial to code.  Good luck!

Comment: @Will Thanks will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a tag. In XAML, collection controls like `ListView` select the actual class instance you gave them. They try to avoid making you deal with `ListViewItems` in your code as much as possible. So `e.ClickedItem` in your event handler won't be the `ListViewItem`; it'll be *your* item, one of the `Games` instances you provided to `ListView.ItemsSource` in your `List<Games>`. No need to mess with `Tag` like in Grandpa's day.

```
private void listView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //var lv = sender as ListView;
    Games clickedGames = e.ClickedItem as Games;

    //  Do stuff with the clicked item. 
}
```

By the way, it looks from your code as if `listofGames` is a private field. That's not a good idea. Since it's not `ObservableCollection`, anything additions to or removals from that list won't be reflected in the `ListView`, so the List should really be local to the `OnLoaded` method, to prevent that from happening. Or better yet, change its type to `ObservableCollection<Games>`. That'll be a drop-in replacement for `List<T>`.

As I've said, I think you unfortunately stumbled on a very bad tutorial.

The "Correct" way to do this (and it really is, in practice) is to have a viewmodel which has your `Games` collection as a public property, and a `public Games SelectedGame` property as well. Then you'd bind those to `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` on the `ListView`, respectively. No `ItemClicked` handler. But I hesitate to urge you too strongly to drop what you're doing and start over.

Comment: Nice explanation. Its Been so long that I've used `Tag` for something. Really Grandpa's days....

Comment: Right, so I will look into the viewmodel first. See if that works out. Do you have a example code? Or maybe a website that has an example? Thanks for the great explanation as well, it helps a lot!

Comment: @Chris Here's one that looks very "correct": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/

Comment: @Chris ...he's using `x:Bind` rather than `Binding` but IIRC `x:Bind` is just a slightly more lightweight equivalent of `Binding`, basically does the same job.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Right, I'm starting to understand how this works now. I will see if I can manage to refactor my code to use MVVM. Thanks for all the help!